# что означают директивы конфигурации apache

Tags: apache2

в файле конфигурации есть такие строки

```
 <Directory /var/www/ua>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

что они делают? и как мне открыть доступ к определенной директории например /var/www/ua/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- про директиву [directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)
- про директиву [options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options)
- про директиву [allowoverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- про директиву [require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

> как мне открыть доступ к определенной директории например `/var/www/ua/files`

скорее всего, просто «не закрывайте» доступ к этому каталогу.

если у вас возникают ошибки при доступе к этому каталогу, дополните вопрос или напишите про ошибки в новом вопросе.